# Google Cloud Endpoints Migration v1 to v2

Tags: google-cloud-platform

As per a google mail I received I am trying to migrate my endpoints code from v1 to v2 as per the directions given on this link.

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating

When I try executing gradle endpointsDiscoveryDocs I am getting the following error

Execution failed for task ':endpointsDiscoveryDocs'.

> com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.isSubtypeOf(Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Z

I tried with stacktrace option but didn't get any clue as to how I can fix this.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
(Sorry have not enough reputation to just add a comment)
I found an answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-endpoints/O0YALBKx1tY which says to add dependency in "classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'". It didn't work for me, but maybe for you.